Tailscale login issue "Something went wrong"
A couple of days ago I finished building my own private 10 inch network rack containing an openWRT router appliance, a managed switch, some upgraded Lenovo M700 ThinkCentres to run a couple of dockerized servers and a rather large Raspberry Pi CM4 cluster.
I installed Tailscale on the openWRT router, my personal and work laptops, both running the latest Debian 12 and - using the Google Playstore app - on my Tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite, latest LineageOS on Android 14) and my phone (Samsung Galaxy A12, Android 12).
Using GitHub as my identity provider, I logged into Tailscale on the router, both my laptops and my tablet without an issue.
However, on my phone, whenever I get past the GitHub login screen in the browser, the Tailscale app tells me "Something went wrong" and shows me a "Try again" button, which - despite click-spamming it 1000000 times a second - doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Surprise!
I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app via the Playstore, installing it via a downloadable .apk and restarting my phone. Nothing worked.
I could also try installing a legacy version from F-Droid, but their latest version is so old, I am hesitating.
Any tips you can give me to resolve this issue?
